# Natural join output doesn't appear in table

Tags: postgresql, join, dbeaver

I used this query:

```
select *
into airbnb_parcels
from pcpao_res 
natural join AIRBNB_PARCELS;
```

and got:

> Error: relation "airbnb_parcels" already exits.

[image]In DBeaver I used the following query:

SELECT * FROM pcpao_res
NATURAL JOIN airbnb_parcels;

But the resulting data only appears in the "output" window below the query panel, not the actual table. I've saved the project, committed the query, etc. but it won't update the table.

It's a large dataset so in the screenshots I opened up a filter on the same column in both the query window and the table window to show how values are present in the former but not the latter.

What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "not the actual table"? You run a SELECT query. DId you expect the table(s) to be updated?

Comment: RE: yper-crazhat-cube... yeah I guess. SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO are giving me "table already exists". I know this is super basic but I don't understand why previous SELECT INTO queries moved data into the table but now I'm getting "table already exists" errors.

Comment: Well, you don't show us any SELECT INTO or INSERT. You only showed a SELECT.

Comment: updated my question to include another screenshot

Comment: Please post the code as text, not images and screenshots.

Comment: here ya go: select * 
into airbnb_parcels
from pcpao_res
natural join AIRBNB_PARCELS;

Comment: Okay, so I know SELECT INTO is for creating new tables now--so I tried INSERT INTO with the following query:
INSERT * 
into airbnb_parcels
from pcpao_res
natural join AIRBNB_PARCELS;

and got the following error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "*"

Comment: The error message says exactly what's wrong. Remove that asterisk. And you still need a select clause after the `insert into airbnb_parcels`. You can't just make up SQL and expect it to work. Strongly suggest you read an SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest to read carefully the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html):

---

## SELECT INTO

SELECT INTO — define a new table from the results of a query

### Description

SELECT INTO **creates a new table** and fills it with data computed by a query. **The data is not returned to the client**, as it is with a normal SELECT. The new table's columns have the names and data types associated with the output columns of the SELECT.

### Notes

CREATE TABLE AS is functionally similar to SELECT INTO. **CREATE TABLE AS is the recommended syntax**, since this form of SELECT INTO is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset of the functionality provided by SELECT INTO.

---

That is:

- SELECT INTO creates a new table, the new table must not exists previously.
- INSERT INTO requires an existent table.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int, name text);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1, '1111'),(2, '2222'),(3, '3333');


-- Correct, t2 doesn't exists.

SELECT id, name INTO t2 FROM t1;


SELECT id, name FROM t2;

id | name
-: | :---
 1 | 1111
 2 | 2222
 3 | 3333
```

```
CREATE TABLE t3 (id int, name text);

-- Error, t3 already exists
SELECT id, name INTO t3 FROM t1;
```

> ERROR:  relation "t3" already exists

```
-- Error, t4 doesn't exists
INSERT INTO t4
SELECT id, name FROM t1;
```

> ERROR:  relation "t4" does not exist
>   LINE 1: INSERT INTO t4
>                       ^

```
-- Correct, t3 already exists
INSERT INTO t3
SELECT id, name FROM t1;

SELECT * FROM t3;

id | name
-: | :---
 1 | 1111
 2 | 2222
 3 | 3333
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=61f984d507d97de9819f7a77807232a3)*

Comment: Thanks, I've since read through the documentation and have resolved the issue.